# create adjacency matrix from a file using python and save output file in a .mat format

Tags: file, dictionary, multidimensional-array, adjacency-matrix

I have a sample dataset similar to this:
Toyota Camry
Toyota Avalon
Honda Civic
Honda Accord
Volkswagen Passat
Volkswagen Jetta

In this dataset, I need to count how many unique values in the first column and second column. Then for each unique value how many values are connected with column two values. Example- Toyota is connected with Camby and Avalon. I need to create an adjacency m*n matrix where m=number of unique value in the first column and n=number of unique value in the second column. My final output looks like this:

```
    Camry   Avalon  Civic   Accord  Passat  Jetta
```

Toyota        1   1   0   0   0   0
Honda         0   0   1   1   0   0
Volkswagen    0   0   0   0   1   1

I need some help on how to solve this by python.

Comment: Is the dataset in a file? Is all the data in a single line or one line per brand-model?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call what you want an [*adjacency matrix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). However, the desired structure can be made quite easily (see comments in code):

```
import pandas
import StringIO
dataset = '''Toyota Camry
Toyota Avalon
Honda Civic
Honda Accord
Volkswagen Passat
Volkswagen Jetta'''
# read the dataset into DataFrame d
d = pandas.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(dataset), ' ', header=None, names=(0, 1))
# make output DataFrame x with rows from first and columns from second input column
x = pandas.DataFrame(0, index=d[0].unique(), columns=d[1].unique())
# set the existing combinations to 1
for e in d.itertuples(index=False, name=None):
    x.at[e] = 1
```